# На сайте на django есть рекламные баннеры с ссылкой для перехода на сайт рекламы, как посчитать клики на ссылку и сохранить их в базу данных?

Tags: django, site, реклама

Как реализовать счетчик кликов при переходе на ссылку рекламы?

```html
views.py
def index(request):
    context_dict = {}
    banner = Banner.objects.all()
    comments_count = Comment.objects.all().count()
    comments_item = Item.objects.all().count()
    context_dict['comments_count'] = comments_count
    context_dict['comments_item'] = comments_item
    context_dict['banner'] = banner

    response = render(request, 'webapp/index.html', context=context_dict)
    return response

models.py 
class Banner(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, verbose_name='Наименование', blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Картинка', storage=SelectelImageStorage)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, verbose_name='Описание', null=True)
    link = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Ccылка на рекламу')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Рекламный баннер"
        verbose_name_plural = "Рекламные баннеры"
        
        
banner.html
{% if banner %}
{% for b in banner %}
<div class="top-categories-2">

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext"></div>
  <a href="{{b.link}}">
  <img class="img-banner" src="{{b.image.url}}" style="width:550px;height:250px;"></a>
  
  <a href="{{b.link}}"><div class="text-banner">{{b.description|truncatechars:200 }}<br><p class="banner-podrob">ПОДРОБНЕЕ ➡ <div class="arrow-1"></div></p></div></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>

</div>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: В питоне не силён, но почему нельзя добавить ко всем рекламным ссылкам определённый класс, к которому будет добавлен обработчик события click. Затем, в обработчике, запрос в БД и перенаправление по ссылке. Или я что-то не понимаю?